# why virtualenv always creating directory with python2.7?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

virtual workspace always contains only python2.7

```
python -V
Python 3.6.5

virtualenv vitual_workspace
New python executable in vitual_workspace/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in vitual_workspace/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
```

after activating the workspace

```
python -V
Python 2.7.15
```

Comment: try running `virtualenv virtual_workspace -p $(which python)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new virtualenv with python3:

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname
```